# How to access the shapes of math-mode characters in text-mode?

Tags: math-mode, fonts, text

Somewhere I read about egreg's `\ensuremath`-only-when-really-needed-campaign and I was convinced by it, but I often need to use some mathematical shapes in the context of "text" and I was wondering if commands like the following should also be barred by the idea of this campaign?

```
\DeclareTextCommand{\textnull}{TU}{$\varnothing$}
\DeclareTextCommand{\textnull}{OT1}{$\varnothing$}
\DeclareTextCommand{\textnull}{T1}{$\varnothing$}
\DeclareTextCommand{\textempty}{TU}{$\emptyset$}
\DeclareTextCommand{\textempty}{OT1}{$\emptyset$}
\DeclareTextCommand{\textempty}{T1}{$\emptyset$}
```

I think they should be, because technically where I will be using these symbols will not be a place for "maths", so now my actual question is how to access these shapes from fonts and call them in TeX? Irrespective of mode, just accessing a font-shape. If the method is different for different engines, I would love to know all of them.

Comment: Please explain what you mean by `context of "text" `? I don't see any benefit of using `\textnull{}` over `$\varnothing$`.

Comment: there  is no advantage of having encoding here, just `\newcommand\textnull{$\varnothing$}`  but I would use `$\varnothing$` directly, apart from anything else it avoids worrying about the following space

Comment: @daleif if my understanding is correct, there is a difference between text and math mode, right? I am not a mathematician, but in my field also we use `$\varnothing$` where we are actually not doing any maths. So in this case I would love to use that visual shape without invoking the math-mode.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle okay, but still because of the reason mentioned above I am curious to know how these shapes are called internally.

Comment: You could use the math font as a text font and some charcters (including this one, probably) will get reasoable spacing but why? It would make no difference at all in the generated output

Comment: Even if you are not a mathematician, `\varnothing` is still a math symbol and should be treated like that. It is similar to when non-mathematicians write negative numbers in a table, they should be in math mode otherwise it is just `hyphen 2` not `minus 2`.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle and @daleif thanks for the suggestions. I will use `$\varnothing$` only.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`amssymb` defines

```
\DeclareSymbolFont{AMSb}{U}{msb}{m}{n}
 ...
\DeclareMathSymbol{\varnothing}     {\mathord}{AMSb}{"3F}
```

So you can access this in text mode as

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
 
\newcommand\textvarnothing{{\usefont{U}{msb}{m}{n}\symbol{"3F}}}

\begin{document}

Look \textvarnothing\ no math.

\end{document}
```

but I see no advantages over `$\varnothing$`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!